# Extract id using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract `id` but they will give me none kindly any solution you suggest me

[image]

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import time
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class BarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bar'
      
    def start_requests(self):
        keywords=['Alsace']
        for keyword in keywords:
            amaz_url=f"https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/region/{keyword}/reparateur-electromenager"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=amaz_url,callback=self.parse,meta={'keyword':keyword})

    def parse(self,response):
        keyword=response.meta['keyword']
        for link in response.xpath("//li[@class='bi bi-generic']//@id"):
            yield{
                'id':link
                }
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code instead of the picture ?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over selectors not values.

Change this line..

```
for link in response.xpath("//li[@class='bi bi-generic']//@id"):
```

to

```
for link in response.xpath("//li[@class='bi bi-generic']//@id").getall():
```

Source: [Scrapy Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#:%7E:text=a%5Bcontains(%40href%2C%20%22image%22)%5D/%40href)

Comment: this is not work for me

Comment: This website has Cloudflare protection, if you repeatedly request the website, it'll show you a captcha instead of the requested page. Try using selenium and adding delays in between to avoid being blocked,

Comment: I am also using an API_KEY with these website

Comment: for bypass the cloudfare protection

Comment: Then please share the code which you're having issues with. As for the code in question, captcha is the issue.

Comment: You can share the part of the problematic code only, or if you think the entire code is needed then you can mask the API Key.